# Skilearn ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I am attempting to verify version of my Sklearn to verify the proper installation, earlier I was having an issue where I had to change my registry value of `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem@LongPathEnabled` value to `1`.
Then I was able to install the files how ever, now when I attempt to check the version of my skilearn I get the following:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/terry/pyversions.py", line 11, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .fixes import np_version
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 384, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 179, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from ._procrustes import procrustes
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_procrustes.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import orthogonal_procrustes
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 195, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Users\terry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 215, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

My versions are as follows:
Python: 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 01:54:44) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
scipy: 1.4.1
numpy: 1.18.0
matplotlib: 3.1.2
pandas: 0.25.3

Please what do I need to do to fix my errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am leaving this up to help others, I found the solution, had to unistall completely, reinstall and changing the reg file to allow long path download may have played a role in the beginning.